# IndexError is raised when trying to perform comparison in while loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, while-loop, index-error

I am aware of indexError in python but I am unable to understand the logic behind my code throwing this error. I am not getting why the error is thrown for an existing list on using it as a condition in while loop.

```
def solve(A, B):
    cumsum = [A[0]] * len(A)
    for i in range(1,len(A)):
        cumsum[i] = cumsum[i-1] + A[i]
    final_arr = []
    for val in B:
        index = 0
        print(index, cumsum)
        print("INDEX Value:", cumsum[index])
        print(val)
        while (cumsum[index] <= val):
            index+=1
        final_arr.append(index)
    return final_arr

A = [3, 4, 4, 6] 
B = [20, 4, 10, 2]
print(solve(A,B))
```

The output I received on the online compiler is, as below

```
0 [3, 7, 11, 17]
INDEX Value: 3
20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 23, in <module>
File "<string>", line 14, in solve
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The print function has no qualms in accessing the same index in the same list but as a while loop condition(Comparison) IndexError is thrown

Comment: Which lines are line 23 and line 14?

Comment: Think carefully about the line `while (cumsum[index] <= val):` — `val` is an element of `B`, and two of those values are greater than the length of `A`, which is what you're using to build `cumsum`.

Comment: @ZacAnger I'm not getting your point. Would it be possible for you to explain more? Like I'm not understanding why you are referring the length of list A here?

Comment: `cumsum` is `[3,3,3,3]`. `for val in B` — the first `val` is `20`. `while (cumsum[index] <= val): index +=1` — you're incrementing until `index` is `20`. Once you hit `4`, you're out of range, because `len(cumsum)` is `4`, so the only valid indices are 0-3.

Comment: @ZacAnger. The first line of the output corresponds to the `index`, here `0` and the remaining is the cumsum list value. The 2nd line corresponds to the `cumsum[0]` which gives out `3` and the first element of `B` is `20`. So the while loop starts with the cumsum[0] which is less than `20` so the loop becomes true. But the loop throws the IndexError for the first iteration itself, which is what the above output shows.